# ListView.builder does not show items after adding them to list FLUTTER

Tags: android, listview, flutter

I have a ListView.builder that reads all items from a list and shows them to the user. The builder is child of a RefreshIndicator, which adds an item when updating. However, the item is only shown in the listView when I rebuild the entire widget. Why is that and how can I change it so that I see the item immediately after updating? Even after repeated refreshing, no new items appear...
Thx for any help

```
class User {
static String id = 'id-001';
static List<Item> list = [];
}
```

```
class DatabaseService {
  final CollectionReference users = Firestore.instance.collection('users');
  Future fetchAndAddToUserList()async{
     var doc = await users.document(User.id).get();
     User.list.add(doc.data['list']);
  }
}
```

```
Future<Null> _refresh() async {
    await DatabaseService().fetchAndAddToUserList();
    setState(() {
      sortList();
    });
    return;
  }
```

```
RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: _refresh,
          key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
          child: Container(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  item: User.list[index],
                );
              },
              itemCount: User.list.length,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: if you're adding a full list of item you should be doing:

User.list.addAll or User.list = //your list

Comment: Thx, but that doesn't change my problem :/

Comment: Because you're using a static List<Item>. Remove that, fetch the result with your Future call, populate your List and use "setState" when you add those items.

Answer (score 0):

`FutureBuilder` to the rescue.

See https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data